# Sending users to web pages to download Pokemon episodes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python code named seasons.py which uses inputs to open different web pages in which there are links to download Pokémon episodes.

The program has a module called seasons.py where it returns the number of episodes that has the season which was entered. It also needs a number of text files called last.txt, and seasons.txt, last2.txt.

The Pokémon episodes names are formatted like:

```
P0k3M0N.1x01.Es.avi.mp4
```

How can I improve the code and prevent errors? If you could tell me better names for the variables it will be perfect, but if not, it's OK.

```
import webbrowser
import os
import seasons
import time

f1 = open('last.txt', 'r')
f4 = open('last2.txt', 'r')

out = False
list1 = []
list2 = []

for file in os.listdir("."):
    if "P0k3M0N" in file:
        list1.append(file)

for i in list1:
    index = i.find("x")
    str1 = i[index + 1:index + 3]
    list2.append(str1)

print("Last one: " + f1.readline())
print("Last: " + f4.readline())

f1.close()
f4.close()

x = 1
list3 = []
list4 = []

for i in range(int(list2[-1])):
    y = str(x)
    if y in list2:
        list3.append(y)
    x += 1

count1 = 0
count2 = 0

for i in list4:
    count1 += 1

for i in list3:
    count2 += 1

if count1 != 0:
    print("You have: " + str(list4))

if count2 != 0:
    print("You have consecutives from " + list3[0] + " to " + list3[-1])


while out == False:
    print("[1] Full season")
    print("[2] Single episodes: Examples: 1-10 / 1, 2 / 3")
    print("[3] Get out")
    input2 = input()
    input1 = str(input2)
    if input1 == "3":
        out = True
    else:
        if input1 == "1":
            season = input("Season: ")
            episodes = seasons.episodes(season)
            for i in range(episodes):
                if len(str(i + 1)) == 1:
                    url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-" + str(season) + "/capitulo-0" + str(x) + "/pokemon.html"
                    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
                    time.sleep(20)
                else:
                    url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-" + str(season) + "/capitulo-" + str(x) + "/pokemon.html"
                    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
                    time.sleep(20)
        else:
            input4 = input("Season: ")
            season = str(input4)
            file = open('season.txt', 'r')
            total_eps = file.readlines()
            number = total_eps[int(input4) - 1]
            print("This season has " + number + " episodes")
            input3 = input("Episodes: ")
            episodes = str(input3)
            if "-" in episodes:
                index = episodes.find("-")
                first = episodes[:index]
                second = episodes[index + 1:]
                x = int(first)
                numbers = "123456789"
                for i in range(int(second) - int(first) + 1):
                    if str(x) in numbers:
                        url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-" + season + "/capitulo-0" + str(x) + "/pokemon.html"
                        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
                    else:
                        url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-" + season + "/capitulo-" + str(x) + "/pokemon.html"
                        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
                    x += 1
                    if int(second) > 10:
                        time.sleep(10)
                os.remove("last2.txt")
                f3 = open('last2.txt', 'w')
                f3.write(episodes)
                f3.close()
            elif "," in episodes:
                numbers = "123456789"
                count = 0
                list = []
                index = episodes.find(",")
                number = episodes[:index]
                list.append(number)
                while index != -1:
                    index = episodes.find(",")
                    if episodes[index + 1] == " ":
                        episodes = episodes[index + 2:]
                    elif episodes[index + 1] in numbers:
                        episodes = episodes[index + 1:]
                    number = episodes[:index]
                    list.append(number)
                list.pop(-1)
                for i in list:
                    count += 1
                for i in range(count):
                    if len(list[i]) == 1:
                        url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-" + season + "/capitulo-0" + list[i] + "/pokemon.html"
                        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
                    else:
                        url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-" + season + "/capitulo-" + list[i] + "/pokemon.html"
                        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
            else:
                if len(episodes) == 1:
                    url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-" + season + "/capitulo-0" + episodes + "/pokemon.html"
                    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
                    os.remove("last.txt")
                    f2 = open('last.txt', 'w')
                    f2.write(episodes)
                    f2.close()
                else:
                    url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-" + season + "/capitulo-" + episodes + "/pokemon.html"
                    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
                    os.remove("last.txt")
                    f2 = open('last.txt', 'w')
                    f2.write(episodes)
                    f2.close()
```

The other module is here:

```
def episodes(n_season):
    f = open('season.txt', 'r')
    seasons = f.readlines()
    season = seasons[int(n_season) - 1]
    index = season.find('\n')
    return season[:index]
```

seasons.txt contains this:

> 83 34 40 51 64 39 51 53 46 51 51 52 33 49 48 44 47 44

Comment: Does it work as intended?

Comment: Could you update the title of your question to describe what your code is doing? We all want better code here on Code Review!

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save a *lot* of code duplication by using [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
if len(episodes) == 1:
    url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-" + season + "/capitulo-0" + episodes + "/pokemon.html"
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
    os.remove("last.txt")
    f2 = open('last.txt', 'w')
    f2.write(episodes)
    f2.close()
else:
    url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-" + season + "/capitulo-" + episodes + "/pokemon.html"
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
    os.remove("last.txt")
    f2 = open('last.txt', 'w')
    f2.write(episodes)
    f2.close()
```

Becomes (with the `with..as` construct as well):

```
url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-{}/capitulo-{:02d}/pokemon.html"
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url.format(season, episode))
with open('last.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(episodes)
```

Here, the `{:02d}` makes sure that the number has two digits and will fill with `0` if it has not. This also takes away all the code with `numbers=...` to check whether the number is one or two digits. The `format` syntax also happily takes in any type as arguments and calls `str()` on them, so this works:

```
>>> "{:02d}".format(1)
'01'
>>> "{:02d}".format(10)
'10'
```

Also note that when specifying the `'w'` flag, the file will be overwritten, so there is no need to delete it first.

The building of the url and the opening in a webbrowser is ripe to be outsourced to a function:

```
def open_in_new_tab(webbrowser, season, episode):
    url = "http://seriesblanco.com/serie/979/temporada-{}/capitulo-{:02d}/pokemon.html"
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(url.format(season, episode))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
f1 = open('last.txt', 'r')
f4 = open('last2.txt', 'r')

out = False
list1 = []
list2 = []

for file in os.listdir("."):
    if "P0k3M0N" in file:
        list1.append(file)

for i in list1:
    index = i.find("x")
    str1 = i[index + 1:index + 3]
    list2.append(str1)

print("Last one: " + f1.readline())
print("Last: " + f4.readline())

f1.close()
f4.close()
```

I would avoid dealing with files in this way. If there is an error anywhere in between the first two and the last two lines shown above, your code will stop and the file will be left open.

It's better practice to use the `with` statement - that way, if there are any errors, the file will still be closed.

```
with open('last.txt', 'r') as f:
    print("Last one: " + f.readline())

with open('last2.txt', 'r') as f:
    print("Last: " + f.readline())
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know that I could use with to open files. Very helpful

Answer (score 3):

- In general the string handling is a bit more complex than necessary,
  e.g. in `episodes` what you want to do is get the "nth" episode from
  the file, without the newline, so it's better for the reader if you
  just write it that way.  There's no reason to have the `int`
  conversion in there either, that should happen at an outer level while
  parsing user input if at all.  In general it would probably also be
  better for reusability to pass in the filename instead of hardcoding
  it.  E.g. that could look at least like this now:

  ```
  def episodes(n_season):
      with open('season.txt', 'r') as f:
          return f.readlines()[n_season - 1].strip()
  ```
- I'd generally put variables close to where they are used -
  declarations at the top make it just harder to find things
  (e.g. `out`).
- `list1` can be inlined and condensed quite a bit, e.g.:

  ```
  for file in os.listdir("."):
      if "P0k3M0N" in file:
          index = file.find("x")
          str1 = file[index + 1:index + 3]
          list2.append(str1)
  ```

  Then again, the string operation here is better and more readabily
  written with a regular expression, e.g.:

  ```
  list2 = [re.search("(\d)x(\d+)", file).groups()[1]
          for file in os.listdir(".")
          if "P0k3M0N" in file]
  ```

  Also note that by using `file` it's shadowing a standard library
  function, which is arguably bad (since you might forget about it and
  later find out when you try to use the standard `file` function
  instead).

  This regex matches a bit more than what the current version did, but
  again that doesn't seem particularly bad, while at the same time it's
  much easier to get what it does.

  `list2` is still a bad name of course.  Even just `files` would be
  better.
- `x` and it's usage are relatively obscure.  I'm hesitant to suggest
  changes in the block that creates `list3` as I'm relatively sure that
  it doesn't quite work ... `if y in files` means that if `files`
  contains strings like `01` or `10`, and `y = str(x)` means that `y` is
  e.g. `1`, then the test should fail.  Perhaps store only the integers
  in `files` then?
- `list4` is half unused, i.e. it'll always be empty.
- The `count1` / `count2` variables can simply be `len(list4)` /
  `len(list3)`, no need for any more logic.  The message "You have
  consecutives..." doesn't seem to hold up given the logic of the code
  though.  There are no guarantees that you have all elements
  consecutive in `list3`.

Dat loop.  You might want to start putting things into functions etc. to
make things more manageable.  If you find yourself writing the same
thing again with *barely* any difference you should also try to find a
way to reconcile - there are about four duplicate blocks here that
manipulate URLs - those should all be unified.

- `... == False` is better written as `not ...`.
- `else: if ...:` can also be written with one level less nesting as
  `elif ...:`.
- Having a zero prefix for integer formatting is better accomplished by
  [formatting directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings),
  e.g. `"{:02d}".format(1)`.
- Put the URL(s) as constants at the top.  You can much easier change
  them if they're in one place.  In the future you might also want to
  have them overridable as command-line arguments and again it's much
  easier to make those changes if you're already using a single variable
  for it.

Once you have all the duplication cleaned up we can look at more
improvements, but at this point there's just a bit too much going on.